# JBPM6.2 When I restart my system, here will throws an exception

Tags: java, jbpm, jboss6.x

I have defined a process with a service task, it works pretty good except this situation, when it has a running task, i restart my program and then it will throws this exception. Here is my code:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.persistence.jpa");

kBuilder = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get().newDefaultBuilder();
kBuilder.entityManagerFactory(emf);

try {
    addAsset(resources);

    DBUserGroupCallbackImpl callback = new DBUserGroupCallbackImpl(props);
    setUserGroupCallback(callback);

    runtimeManager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(kBuilder.get());
    runtime = runtimeManager.getRuntimeEngine(EmptyContext.get());
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    logger.warn(e.getMessage());
}
```

and when i debug the process, i found:
`runtimeManager = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(kBuilder.get());`

this line throws the Exception, I wonder why ? and how it happened?

PS:I used mysql as the persistence
See error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIqWO.png).

Answer (score 0):

finally i found this is because i register a work handler of the service task out of side, and when when process run it will register the work handler later, but when the system restart, the work handler will not register immediately, so it will throw this exception, here is my code ,when it restart, i register the work handler immediately.

ServicesInstance.jbpmService.registerWorkItemHandler("SendAlarmProcess", new AutoServiceImpl());